# Optimising part of Java Swing code that read HTML documents

Tags: java, html, swing

How can I optimize this part of code?

```
String insertData (String template){

    template=template.replace("###menu1Link###",tbMenu1Link.getText());
    template=template.replace("###menu1Title###",tbMenu1Title.getText()); 
    template=template.replace("###content###",epContent.getText());   
    template=template.replace("###footer###",epFooter.getText()); 
    template=template.replace("###image1###",jfc2.getSelectedFile().getPath());
    template=template.replace("###image2###",jfc2.getSelectedFile().getPath());

    return template ;
}
```

Comment: Why you need to optimize the code?

Comment: I have assignment to optimise that method so that he haven't  have so many lines with same contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the multiple `replace` using a map if this is what you meant by optimizing the code:

```
    void doStuff(String template) {

        Map<String,String> vars = new HashMap<String, String>();
        vars.put("###menu1Link###",tbMenu1Link.getText());
        vars.put("###menu1Title###",tbMenu1Title.getText()); 
        vars.put("###content###",epContent.getText()); 
        //...
        String templateWithData = insertData(template, vars);
    }

    String insertData (String template, Map<String, String> vars){
        for (String key : vars.keySet()) {
            template = template.replace(key, vars.get(key));
        }
        return template ;
    }
```

Is this what you are looking for or you want to optimize the memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your template string, then you could use [String.format(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) and reduce it to one function call.  Here's what I mean:

Right now I'm guessing your template string has text like this:

```
... <a href="###menu1Link###">###menu1Title###</a> ...
```

If you change it to this:

```
... <a href="%s">%s</a> ...
```

Then you could rewrite your function like this:

```
String insertData(String template) {
    return String.format(template,
        tbMenu1Link.getText(),
        tbMenu1Title.getText()
    );
}
```

You just have to make sure that the parameters are in the same order as the `%s` tokens in the template (or use argument index tokens, as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)).